# Show a maintenance page while moving the site

Tags: maintenance-mode

I am going to move the finished drupal site from the sub-directory to root, because the files are quite large, it takes a while to do so, I want to put a html file there to show 'site maintenance in process, be back soon'.

How can I do this while I move everything?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about webserver configuration which belongs on Server Fault.

Comment: I'm afraid @chx is right - if you want your server to do things while Drupal is not working on it at all, it's not quite a Drupal question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First put your site into the maintenance mode than ("Administer > Site configuration > Site maintenance"), and than do the following:

Create the template file for maintenance page as `maintenance-page.tpl.php`.

Tutorial for creating a template file for maintenance page: https://drupal.org/node/195435